# How i can make a damage system without using Touched

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I was trying to make a Kick system in roblox studio, but I don't know a way to make a Humanoid take damage without using the .Touched event, any suggestions?
code below:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player)
    local character = Player.Character or Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    local bv = Instance.new("BodyVelocity")
    bv.MaxForce = Vector3.new(math.huge, math.huge, math.huge)
    bv.Velocity = character.PrimaryPart.CFrame.LookVector * 50
    bv.Parent = character.PrimaryPart
    local animation = Instance.new("Animation")
    animation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://10442940385"
    animation.Parent = character.Humanoid
    local l = character.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
    l:Play()
    local footparticle = game.ServerStorage.Foot:Clone()
    footparticle.Parent = character.RightFoot
    footparticle.Parent = character.LeftFoot
    task.wait(0.2)
    game.Debris:AddItem(bv, 0.00001)
    footparticle.Parent = nil
    footparticle.Parent = nil
    l:Stop()
end)
```

Comment: So what part are you having issues with? Detecting a nearby character when you play the animation workout using the Touched event? Is there a reason you don't want to use the Touched event?

Comment: I dont want to use Touched because on this  system it's hard to use Debounce and i cant disable the Event. I also want to learn how to create a "Hitbox".

Comment: @takezo You should get used to debounces. And, you can disable the event. The `Connect` function returns a `Connection`, so you could do this: `local connection = part.Touched:Connect(function() --[[code here]] end)` and when you're done, you can disable the event by doing `connection:Disconnect()`.

Comment: And how i can make a Hitbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the comments, you are looking to make a damage system, understand hitboxes, and avoid using the Touched event.

A hitbox is simply a region that you define for a limited time where you look for collisions with a player's character model. And detecting collisions is a fairly simple thing; you can even simplify it down to 1 dimension :

## Calculating Collisions

### 1) One Dimension - Point

```cpp
    A*----------------B*
           X*
```

In the region between the points A and B, you would say that X is inside it because it is greater than A and less than B. In code we might express that as :

```lua
local function didHitPoint(a : number, b : number, x : number) : boolean
    return x >= a and x <= b
end
```

Now that's all well and good for a single point in a simple region. But what if you've got something like a square? We need to check if a region overlaps with another.

### 2) One Dimension - Region

```cpp
Case 1) Overlap on left
            A*------------B*
     X*-------Y*

Case 2) Overlap on the right
     A*-------------B*
                X*------------Y*

Case 3) AB larger than XY
    A*---------------B*
          X*---Y*

Case 4) XY larger than AB
           A*----B*
    X*--------------Y*
```

In each of these cases, we would say that the two regions are overlapping. So we need to update our logic :

```lua
local function didHitRegion(a : number, b : number, x : number, y : number) : boolean
    local xInside = x >= a and x <= b
    local yInside = y >= a and y <= b
    local xOutside = x <= a
    local yOutside = y >= b

    -- case 1 and 2 and 3
    if xInside or yInside then
        return true
    end
    
    -- case 4
    if xOutside and yOutside then
        return true
    end

    -- not overlapping in any way
    return false
end
```

### 3) Three Dimensions - Cube

So when it comes to 2 and 3 dimensions (thinking of squares and cube collisions) we can check if each axis has an overlapping region. And if all three dimensions have overlapping regions, we know that our object has collided with the hitbox. So to do this, we need to be able to calculate an axis-aligned bounding box. These are less accurate than object-aligned bounding boxes, but they are easier to conceptualize. Zeux, the technical fellow at Roblox, has this [code sample for quickly computing an AABB](https://gist.github.com/zeux/1a67e8930df782d5474276e218831e22). I have stripped out the comments explaining the code and adapted it for single parts and undoubtedly made it worse in the process, the original is very informative about the performance implications for each line. But using this function, we can calculate a bounding box that always aligns with the XYZ axes, and easily check if we are hitting it.

```lua
-- given a part, return the coordinates representing the minimum and maximum extents of the part
local function computeAABBForPart(part)
    local abs = math.abs
    local inf = math.huge

    local cf = part.CFrame
    local size = part.Size
    local sx, sy, sz = size.X, size.Y, size.Z

    local x, y, z, R00, R01, R02, R10, R11, R12, R20, R21, R22 = cf:components()

    -- https://zeuxcg.org/2010/10/17/aabb-from-obb-with-component-wise-abs/
    local wsx = 0.5 * (abs(R00) * sx + abs(R01) * sy + abs(R02) * sz)
    local wsy = 0.5 * (abs(R10) * sx + abs(R11) * sy + abs(R12) * sz)
    local wsz = 0.5 * (abs(R20) * sx + abs(R21) * sy + abs(R22) * sz)
            
    local minx = x - wsx
    local miny = y - wsy
    local minz = z - wsz

    local maxx = x + wsx
    local maxy = y + wsy
    local maxz = z + wsz
    
    -- rather than returning a Region3, let's return the min and max so we don't have to calculate it again
    return Vector3.new(minx, miny, minz), Vector3.new(maxx, maxy, maxz)
end

-- given two Parts, return whether they are touching
local function didHitBox(part1 : Part, part2 : Part) : boolean
    local part1Min, part1Max = computeAABBForPart(part1)
    local part2Min, part2Max = computeAABBForPart(part2)

    local xOverlaps = didHitRegion(part1Min.X, part1Max.X, part2Min.X, part2Max.X)
    if not xOverlaps then
        return false
    end

    local yOverlaps = didHitRegion(part1Min.Y, part1Max.Y, part2Min.Y, part2Max.Y)
    if not yOverlaps then
        return false
    end

    local zOverlaps = didHitRegion(part1Min.Z, part1Max.Z, part2Min.Z, part2Max.Z)
    if not zOverlaps then
        return false
    end

    -- if we have not escaped by now, we must be colliding
    return true
end
```

All of this is really a simplified version of handling collisions. A more extensive explanation can be found in the book [Real-Time Collision Detection](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9781558607323/real-time-collision-detection), by Christer Ericson.

---

## Detecting Collisions with Character Models

So now that we can detect when two parts are overlapping, we now need a way to decide what parts to compare against our hitbox. For simplicity, we might create a Part to represent the hitbox. And to get the other part, we might loop over each player's character model and grab some part in it.

```lua
-- In a Script placed inside a large transparent Part in the Workspace...
local hitBox = script.Parent
game["Run Service"].Heartbeat:Connect(function(delta)
    local charactersTouching = {}
    for _, player : Player in ipairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        -- if the player has a character in the game, check if they are touching the box
        if player.Character and player.Character.Parent ~= nil then
            for _, part in ipairs(player.Character:GetChildren()) do
                -- quick escape if we've already detected a touch
                if charactersTouching[player.Name] then
                    continue
                end
                if part:IsA("BasePart") then
                    if didHitBox(touchPart, part) then
                        charactersTouching[player.Name] = true
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    
    -- DEBUG : Turn the box green if a player is inside the box, otherwise turn red
    local isTouching = next(charactersTouching) ~= nil  
    touchPart.Color = if isTouching then Color3.new(0, 1, 0) else Color3.new(1, 0, 0)

    -- list the hit players
    --print("Players hit : " .. table.concat(playersHit, ", "))
end)
```

| Not Touching | Touching | DEBUG - with AABB visualized |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: A cube in the workspace sits near a character. The cube is red.] | [image: A character stands inside the cube. The cube is green.] | [image: a character stands next to a cube. But the cube is still green due to inaccuracies with AABB collisions detection] |

You may have noticed that in the last image, the character isn't *really* touching the hitbox. This is due to the inaccuracies with AABB collisions. AABB collision detection tends to be relatively fast, and some strategies will use AABB as a preliminary test before doing more accurate, and more expensive checks.

---

## Putting it all together

Okay, all of that was to get to here. We need to ...

1. play the kick animation
2. spawn the hitbox
3. collect a list of which players have been hit
4. despawn the hitbox

```lua
-- MAKE SURE TO PULL IN THE computeAABBForPart, didHitBox, and didHitRegion FUNCTIONS DEFINED ABOVE
game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()

    -- play the animation
    local animation = Instance.new("Animation")
    animation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://10442940385"
    animation.Parent = character.Humanoid
    local loadedAnimation = character.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
    loadedAnimation:Play()

    -- create some particles
    local footparticleLeft = game.ServerStorage.Foot:Clone()
    local footparticleRight = game.ServerStorage.Foot:Clone()
    footparticleLeft.Parent = character.LeftFoot
    footparticleRight.Parent = character.RightFoot

    -- spawn the invisible hitbox
    -- NOTE : adjust the size and positioning yourself
    local hitbox = Instance.new("Part")
    hitbox.Anchored = true
    hitbox.CFrame = character:GetPrimaryPartCFrame() * CFrame.new(0, 0, -5)
    hitbox.Size = Vector3.new(2, 2, 4)
    hitbox.CanCollide = false
    hitbox.Transparency = 1.0
    hitbox.Parent = game.Workspace

    -- wait a moment
    task.wait(0.2)

    -- check which players are in the hitbox
    local hitPlayers = {} -- <name : String, player> 
    for _, otherPlayer in ipairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        if otherPlayer ~= player then
            if otherPlayer.Character and otherPlayer.Character.Parent ~= nil then
                for _, part in ipairs(otherPlayer.Character:GetChildren()) do
                    if hitPlayers[otherPlayer.Name] then
                        continue
                    end
                    if part:IsA("BasePart") then
                        if didHitBox(hitbox, part) then
                            hitPlayers[otherPlayer.Name] = otherPlayer
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

    -- deal damage to the players caught in the hitbox
    local DAMAGE = 10
    for name, player in pairs(hitPlayers) do
        -- the player should have a character still, but be safe about it
        if player.Character then
            player.Character.Humanoid:TakeDamage(DAMAGE)
        end
    end

    -- clean up
    footparticleLeft:Destroy()
    footparticleRight:Destroy()
    loadedAnimation:Stop()
    animation:Destroy()
    hitbox:Destroy()
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Heyo, I wanted to add another answer to show how you could do this with the Touched event as well, because it simplifies a lot of the answer.

Since you were worried about debouncing the Touched event, I actually wrote up how to do this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63252504/lua-roblox-api-how-can-i-debounce-a-player-character-that-runs-into-a-box/63257964#63257964) a while ago. Essentially, you need to keep count of how many pieces of a character model are touching a part, and only clear the debounce flag once all the pieces have stopped touching.

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    local character = player.Character
    if not character then
        return
    end

    -- play the animation
    local animation = Instance.new("Animation")
    animation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://10442940385"
    animation.Parent = character.Humanoid
    local loadedAnimation = character.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
    loadedAnimation:Play()

    -- create some particles
    local footparticleLeft = game.ServerStorage.Foot:Clone()
    local footparticleRight = game.ServerStorage.Foot:Clone()
    footparticleLeft.Parent = character.LeftFoot
    footparticleRight.Parent = character.RightFoot

    -- spawn the invisible hitbox
    -- NOTE : adjust the size and positioning yourself
    local hitbox = Instance.new("Part")
    hitbox.Anchored = true
    hitbox.CFrame = character:GetPrimaryPartCFrame() * CFrame.new(0, 0, -5)
    hitbox.Size = Vector3.new(2, 2, 4)
    hitbox.CanCollide = false
    hitbox.Transparency = 1.0
    hitbox.Parent = game.Workspace

    -- listen for players touching the hitbox
    local hitPlayers = {} -- <player : Player, touchCount : number> 
    local touchedConnection = hitbox.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
        local otherPlayer = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(otherPart.Parent)
        if otherPlayer then
            if hitPlayers[otherPlayer] then
                -- increment the counter if they are already touching
                hitPlayers[otherPlayer] += 1
            else
                hitPlayers[otherPlayer] = 1
            end
        end
    end)
    local touchEndedConnection = hitbox.TouchEnded:Connect(function(otherPart)
        local otherPlayer = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(otherPart.Parent)
        if otherPlayer then
            hitPlayers[otherPlayer] -= 1
            if hitPlayers[otherPlayer] == 0 then
                hitPlayers[otherPlayer] = nil
            end
        end
    end)

    -- wait a moment for the animation to play
    task.wait(0.2)

    -- deal damage to the players caught in the hitbox
    local DAMAGE = 10
    for plr, _ in pairs(hitPlayers) do
        if plr ~= player then 
            -- the player should have a character still, but be safe about it
            if plr.Character then
                plr.Character.Humanoid:TakeDamage(DAMAGE)
            end
        end
    end

    -- clean up
    footparticleLeft:Destroy()
    footparticleRight:Destroy()
    loadedAnimation:Stop()
    animation:Destroy()
    hitbox:Destroy()
    touchedConnection:Disconnect()
    touchEndedConnection:Disconnect()
end)
```