# Attempt to index nil with characterAdded

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I need to get the character of the player for a system thats give a damage if a part is touched but this occur by a normal script and not a local script and i want to prevent the character take damage. How i can make this?

I tried to make this code but didn't worked.

```
for i, v in pairs(script.Parent:GetChildren()) do
    if v:IsA("MeshPart") then
        v.Touched:Connect(function(p)
            local db = true
            local char = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(p.Parent).CharacterAdded:Wait()
            if char then
                if p.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") ~= char.Humanoid and db == true then
                    db = false
                    p.Parent.Humanoid.Health -= 150
                    task.wait(3)
                    db = true
                end
            end
        end)
    end
end
```

Comment: Is your goal to prevent a specific player from getting damaged by this part or to prevent all players from getting damaged?

Comment: If you're looking to debounce collisions with a box, I would recommend looking at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63252504/lua-roblox-api-how-can-i-debounce-a-player-character-that-runs-into-a-box

Answer (score 0):

You should connect the touched event to the kill brick, not the players limbs and you also need to do `=-` not `-=`

```lua
local killBrick = script.Parent

killBrick.Touched:Connect(function(p)
    local db = true
    if p.Parent:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid") then -- make sure the thing its touching is a player/has a humanoid
        if db == true then
            db = false
            p.Parent:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid").Health =- 150
            task.wait(3)
            db = true
        end
    end
end)
```

Also make sure this is a server script and that its parented to the kill brick
If you want to protect someone from this just do `p.Parent.Name == "Username"`

Comment: I already put the script on the meshpart and =- will return a error, no?