# Tag a player who touches script.Parent

Tags: lua, roblox

So I want this to tag a player, however it just does nothing!

```
local playersTouching = {}

local function onPartTouched(part, player)
    if part == script.Parent and player and player:IsA("Player") then
        player:SetAttribute("Hiding", true)
        playersTouching[player] = true
    end
end

local function onPartTouchEnded(part, player)
    if part == script.Parent and player and player:IsA("Player") then
        player:SetAttribute("Hiding", nil)
        playersTouching[player] = nil
    end
end

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
    local humanoid = otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        onPartTouched(script.Parent, humanoid.Parent)
    end
end)

script.Parent.TouchEnded:Connect(function(otherPart)
    local humanoid = otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        onPartTouchEnded(script.Parent, humanoid.Parent)
    end
end)
```

So I run this on Roblox, and the Player touches the `script.Parent`, but the player doesn't get tagged. The goal of this is to detect when the player is touching `otherPart` along with `script.Parent`. If my method doesnt work please suggest another method. Thx!

**AMENDMENT**: Now my detection script ain't working. So is it the same issue where I am getting the character instead of the player?:

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(player)
    print("TOUCHED")
    if player:GetAttribute("Hiding") then
        print("tag player touch????")
    else
        print("HMM")

    end
end)
```

Comment: note: you send `script.Parent` as an argument to OnPartTouched, but then check if that argument is equal to `script.Parent`, which it always will be. I also suggest renaming `player` variables in your program to `character`, as a character model is not of type Player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the simple mistake of confusing a [Player](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player) object with their [character model](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player#Character) that runs around the Workspace. They both have the same name, but are different classes.

Looking at these lines :

```
onPartTouched(script.Parent, humanoid.Parent)

-- which calls ... 

local function onPartTouched(part, player)
    if part == script.Parent and player and player:IsA("Player") then
```

You are checking if the `player` variable `IsA("Player")`, but this check will always be false because the `humanoid.Parent` is a Model, not a Player.

A better way to get the Player is to use [Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter()](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Players#GetPlayerFromCharacter). And something to be careful about when it comes to the `Touched` and `TouchEnded` signals is that your character model can fire the signal multiple times. So to make sure that the code only fires once you completely stop touching the part, it's a good idea to keep count of how many parts or touching the block. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63252504/lua-roblox-api-how-can-i-debounce-a-player-character-that-runs-into-a-box/63257964#63257964) for more details.

So try this :

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local playersTouching = {} -- <Player, int>

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
    local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(otherPart.Parent)
    if player then
        -- only set the attribute once
        if not playersTouching[player] then
            playersTouching[player] = 0

            -- do the thing for the first time
            player:SetAttribute("Hiding", true)
            print(player.Name .. " is now hiding")
        end

        -- keep count of the number of objects touching the block
        playersTouching[player] += 1
    end
end)

script.Parent.TouchEnded:Connect(function(otherPart)
    local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(otherPart.Parent)
    if player then
        -- decrement the counter
        playersTouching[player] -= 1

        -- only remove the attribute once all the touching pieces have stopped
        if playersTouching[player] == 0 then
            playersTouching[player] = nil
      
            -- do the thing that happens only once
            player:SetAttribute("Hiding", nil)
            print(player.Name .. " is no longer hiding")
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: Hmm, the issue is my detecting script may also be flawed!
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(player)
 print("TOUCHED")
 if player:GetAttribute("Hiding") then
  print("tag player touch????")
 else
  print("HMM")

 end
end)

Comment: The Touched signal doesn't return a player object though, you have to manually associate the part with the player that owns it. This code you've just shared will only check if the part has a "hiding" attribute.