# I am wondering how I can make this script work on Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

It is supposed to work like if a player steps on a pad, it will turn from green to red, and then back to green. It will also then give a player a tool if they own a certain gamepass. Here's the lines of code:

```
local Potion = game.ServerStorage.BodySwapPotion
local ColorPad = script.Parent.GreenToRed
local GamePassId = 180129712

ColorPad.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local Player = hit.Parent
    local UserId = game.Players:GetUserIdFromNameAsync(Player)
    local LocPlayer = game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayerByUserId(UserId)
    if LocPlayer.UserOwnsGamePassAsync(UserId, GamePassId) then
        local PotionClone = Potion:Clone()
        PotionClone.Parent = Player
    end
    ColorPad.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red") 
    wait(1)
    ColorPad.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Lime green")
end)
```

The error I keep getting is, "attempt to index nil with 'UserOwnsGamePassAsync'".

I've tried everything but a new error always gets in the way. I feel that this is the closest I have gotten though so far. Please help me!

Comment: Apparently your Player doesn't exist. Are you sure your name to id to player conversation is correct?

Comment: It is not supposed to be a specific person, its just for whoever owns the gamepass.

Comment: I know. I'm asking you to perform basic debugging and verify that your chain of functions is correct. [GetUserIdFromNameAsync](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Players#GetUserIdFromNameAsync) for example does not seem to accept anything else than a string. You should add proper error handling anyways since every non player touching the object would crash.

Comment: Okay, but im asking how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The error `attempt to index nil with 'UserOwnsGamePassAsync'` is saying that the `LocPlayer` object simply doesn't exist, and as @Luke100000 pointed out, this means that your system for finding a player based on the name isn't working. But, it's also important to remember that the `Touched` event will fire for everything that touches the part, and that includes things that aren't character models. So you need to handle the case where it's not a player, and simply escape so your code doesn't break.

Roblox has made a very helpful function in the [Players service](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Players) called [GetPlayerFromCharacter](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Players#GetPlayerFromCharacter) that will give you the [Player](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player) object if the object is a character model. From there, you can get the `UserId` from the similarly named property.

Then, when you are checking if a player owns a gamepass, you need to use the [MarketplaceService](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/MarketplaceService), because that's where the `UserOwnsGamePassAsync` function is located.

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")

local Potion = game.ServerStorage.BodySwapPotion
local ColorPad = script.Parent.GreenToRed
local GamePassId = 180129712

ColorPad.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local Player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    -- escape if the thing that touched the color pad isn't a player
    if not Player then
        return
    end
    
    -- change the button color to show we're doing something
    ColorPad.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red") 

    -- check if the player owns the gamepass
    if MarketplaceService:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(Player.UserId, GamePassId) then
        -- give them the potion
        local PotionClone = Potion:Clone()
        PotionClone.Parent = Player.Backpack -- assuming this is a Tool
    end

    -- animate the button color
    wait(1)
    ColorPad.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Lime green")
end)
```

Comment: This will likely give the player a ton of potions, it might be worthwhile to look into [debouncing touches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63252504/lua-roblox-api-how-can-i-debounce-a-player-character-that-runs-into-a-box/63257964#63257964).