# How to tell when a player has stopped touching a part (Roblox Studio)

Tags: function, lua, game-engine, roblox

With help from phloem I was able to make a region 3 script that detects when the player is inside it and it looks like this,

```
while true do
    wait(1)
    local partsInregion = game.Workspace:FindPartsInRegion3(region2, nil, 1000)
    for i, part in pairs(partsInregion) do
        if part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") ~= nil and part.Parent.Name ~= "NextBot" then
            print("Player found in region"..part.Parent.Name)
            local char = part.Parent
            
            local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(char)
            local inSafety = player:WaitForChild("inSafety")
            inSafety.Value = "True"
            
            local valueFound = findValue( playersinSafeZone, player)
            if valueFound then
                print(char.Name .."  Is already apart of the safety  table bro")
            else
                print("Putting this guy in the safety table")
                table.insert(playersinSafeZone,player)
            end
            
        end
    end
end
```

I also have a findValue() function that finds a specific value as show here.

```
local playersinSafeZone = {}
-- findTableValue
local function findValue(whichArray, itemName)
    for currentIndex = 1, #whichArray do
        if whichArray[currentIndex] == itemName then
            --Sends the value of currentIndex back
            return currentIndex
        end
    end
end
```

I understand that I should check if a player is in the table and not detected in the partfindingfunciton inside the Region3 to turn off the 'inSafety' value, but I'm not sure how to put it together into a script. Thanks for the tremendous help so far!

Comment: See the documentation for the [TouchEnded event.](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BasePart#TouchEnded)

Comment: I tried using a touched ended event but it glitches out because the player is Inside the part not just ontop of it, It does the touchended event a little bit after they walk inside

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lua Roblox API: How can I debounce a player/character that runs into a box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63252504/lua-roblox-api-how-can-i-debounce-a-player-character-that-runs-into-a-box)

Answer (score 1):

So I ran into an issue like this a while ago. No, TouchEnded does not work,  all it does it tell when the player has stopped moving on the part.

What you should use is a Region3, it tells whenever the player is inside it or not, which would be used in your case. They're some tutorials on youtube about Region3s.

I hope this answered your question!

Comment: Holy Cow,  you are a life saver man! After watching A YT about region3  it totally makes sense. Just one thing, I can't find a way to use logic to tell me when a player is not in the region anymore. I've tried using tables to log them but idk how to remove the player once they aren't touching. ( It works great  when a player is inside the part so kudos to you, I basically just want to fire a remote event when the player isn't in the region)

Comment: I will try my best to find out how!

Comment: The "FindPartsInRegion3()" function always gives you an update of the parts inside the region. You can check what player they belong to  and give change the player's value of InSafety, and add the players name to a table. Once you exit, the "FindPartsInRegion3()" function will not print it. So, if it is not found in the function and found in the table, you can remove it from the table. If the player's Name in game.Players isnt in the table, you can change the value of "InSafety".

Comment: This is the order you should script it in.

Comment: ............Genius!

Comment: Okay, ive been mulling this over for a. while and I can't seem to wrap my mind around how to launch a function when there is a player in the table but not detected every second in the Region3GetParts. I have edited my question to show the new code I have and you have already done wonders but do you think you would know how to launch a function like the one described above?